# List<T> to datatable returns empty - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I am using below code to populate `datatable` from `List<double[]> list`
But the datatable is not populated.

```
private void LoadThis(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            X model = DataContext as X;

            List<double[]> list = new List<double[]>();
            for (int i = 0; i < model.RowFijtable; i++)
            {
                double[] rowdata = new double[model.ColFijtable];
                for (int j = 0; j < model.ColFijtable; j++)
                {
                    rowdata[j] = model.TauTable[i, j];
                }
                list.Add(rowdata);
            }
            DataTable table = ConvertListToDataTable(list);
            dataGridView1.ItemsSource = table.AsDataView(); //Is this correct?
}

  private DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<double[]> list)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        // Get max columns.
        int columns = 0;
        foreach (var array in list)
        {
            if (array.Length > columns)
            {
                columns = array.Length;
            }
        }

        // Add columns.
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
        {
            table.Columns.Add();
        }

        // Add rows.
        foreach (var array in list)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(array);
        }

        return table;
    }
```

This is how I placed the information in `XAML`

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
     VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
     Name="dataGridView1"
     Loaded="LoadThis"
     ItemsSource="{Binding}"
     AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
</Grid>
```

I can see that the number of columns and rows are passed on correctly to the datatable but no data values even though List has complete dataset!

I also tried doing `dataGridView1.DataSource = table;` but this keeps me error as "Datagrid does not contain the definition of DataSource"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `table.Rows.Add(array)` seems to put the entire array into the first column value. To put the array elements into successive columns, try this:

```
    private DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<double[]> list)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        // Get max columns.
        int columns = 0;
        foreach (var array in list)
        {
            if (array.Length > columns)
            {
                columns = array.Length;
            }
        }

        // Add columns.
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
        {
            // Provide default column name & data type
            table.Columns.Add("Column" + (i+1).ToString(), typeof(double) );
        }

        // Add rows.
        foreach (var array in list)
        {
            // assign each array element to the appropriate column
            var row = table.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i )
                row.SetField( i, array[i] );
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return table;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Is there any way to add "row names" too? like the table.columns.add() statement? @JohnD

Comment: There's no built-in concept of a row name - however you could add a column at the beginning called "RowDescription" or "RowName" and fill it yourself with information that summarises the row.